# ANR after long app uptime

Tags: android, multithreading

Our app sometimes locks up with ANR after it has been in device foreground for a long time, say over night. The app starts, but only shows black screen. Back and home buttons don't respond until about 10 seconds after they were pressed.

Running the app in strict mode, doesn't highlight any problems.  All network activity, and long running tasks are done on background threads.

Looking at the traces file for our app, I can't identify the "main" thread, so I can't diagnose what is locking up the UI.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491328/application-going-into-anr-mode) sounds like the same symptoms, but our app doesn't use the offending library: JmDNS.

```
----- pid 21220 at 2013-11-26 08:32:09 -----
Cmd line: com.mygreatapp.reptile

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)

"java.lang.ProcessManager" daemon prio=5 tid=11 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4242b590 self=0x60d506f0
  | sysTid=21305 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1626388752
  | schedstat=( 1686960 1679167 34 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x42413810> (a java.util.HashMap)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.ProcessManager.waitForMoreChildren(ProcessManager.java:140)
  at java.lang.ProcessManager.watchChildren(ProcessManager.java:105)
  at java.lang.ProcessManager.access$000(ProcessManager.java:40)
  at java.lang.ProcessManager$1.run(ProcessManager.java:58)

"Thread-30992" prio=5 tid=1 VMWAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4528c3f8 self=0x60f0e488
  | sysTid=21220 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074544432
  | schedstat=( 500594685618 30706953168 460765 ) utm=44353 stm=5705 core=3
  #00  pc 0000dca0  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
  #01  pc 00012e44  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
  #02  pc 00012ea0  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+60)
  #03  pc 0004a1af  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #04  pc 0003a4a1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #05  pc 0004d585  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+452)
  #06  pc 00000dcf  /system/bin/app_process
  #07  pc 00017123  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+38)
  #08  pc 00000b34  /system/bin/app_process
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"pool-4-thread-1" prio=5 tid=15 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41e20c58 self=0x410e1520
  | sysTid=21281 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1089112720
  | schedstat=( 102424840 33825634 517 ) utm=6 stm=3 core=3
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41cc4b30> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=15 (pool-4-thread-1)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Thread-30976" prio=5 tid=29 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41e407c8 self=0x60b1cdf0
  | sysTid=21279 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1466754424
  | schedstat=( 22878231471 2961981162 8385 ) utm=2103 stm=184 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41d189a8> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=29 (Thread-30976)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at crittercism.android.cq.a((null):-1)
  at crittercism.android.cv.run((null):-1)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorThread" prio=5 tid=28 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41f7d9c8 self=0x60b5f5d0
  | sysTid=21277 nice=-8 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1466031464
  | schedstat=( 629417858 226101457 2481 ) utm=62 stm=0 core=0
  #00  pc 0000da70  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
  #01  pc 00014899  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+96)
  #02  pc 00014b01  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+104)
  #03  pc 00023f5d  /system/lib/libgui.so (android::SensorEventQueue::waitForEvent() const+36)
  #04  pc 0007e085  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
  #05  pc 0001def0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
  #06  pc 0004d14b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+394)
  #07  pc 00000214  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
  at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager.sensors_data_poll(Native Method)
  at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorThread$SensorThreadRunnable.run(SystemSensorManager.java:133)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Binder_4" prio=5 tid=26 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41cedae0 self=0x58c98ec0
  | sysTid=21272 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1488945728
  | schedstat=( 701164079 37010713 402 ) utm=66 stm=4 core=0
  #00  pc 0000cb90  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 00027fcd  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
  #02  pc 00016bfd  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+124)
  #03  pc 000173af  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
  #04  pc 0001b171  /system/lib/libbinder.so
  #05  pc 0001104f  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
  #06  pc 0004ba7b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
  #07  pc 00010bb5  /system/lib/libutils.so
  #08  pc 00012e00  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
  #09  pc 00012558  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_3" prio=5 tid=25 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41cfbe58 self=0x58ca4e68
  | sysTid=21271 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1485257944
  | schedstat=( 29564295 25159912 195 ) utm=1 stm=1 core=0
  #00  pc 0000cb90  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 00027fcd  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
  #02  pc 00016bfd  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+124)
  #03  pc 000173af  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
  #04  pc 0001b171  /system/lib/libbinder.so
  #05  pc 0001104f  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
  #06  pc 0004ba7b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
  #07  pc 00010bb5  /system/lib/libutils.so
  #08  pc 00012e00  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
  #09  pc 00012558  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"AsyncTask #5" prio=5 tid=24 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41cf26f0 self=0x57682458
  | sysTid=21266 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1464170168
  | schedstat=( 135820845754 105683034246 2907951 ) utm=10204 stm=3378 core=2
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41d1d280> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=24 (AsyncTask #5)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #4" prio=5 tid=23 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41edc388 self=0x57682008
  | sysTid=21265 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1465817672
  | schedstat=( 132577127701 105107036747 2873808 ) utm=9956 stm=3301 core=2
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41c8dbe0> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=23 (AsyncTask #4)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"RefQueueWorker@org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute@41eff7c8" daemon prio=5 tid=22 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41e2ac40 self=0x576129a8
  | sysTid=21262 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1465983376
  | schedstat=( 211376 507582 7 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41f00830> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.RefQueueWorker.run(RefQueueWorker.java:102)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=21 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41ea3cd8 self=0x40e8a150
  | sysTid=21261 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1088988576
  | schedstat=( 147758360521 113209347880 3132414 ) utm=11120 stm=3655 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41eb3510> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=21 (AsyncTask #3)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:813)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:973)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1282)
  at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:207)
  at roboguice.util.SafeAsyncTask$Task.postToUiThreadAndWait(SafeAsyncTask.java:285)
  at roboguice.util.SafeAsyncTask$Task.doFinally(SafeAsyncTask.java:248)
  at roboguice.util.SafeAsyncTask$Task.call(SafeAsyncTask.java:188)
  at roboguice.util.SafeAsyncTask$Task.call(SafeAsyncTask.java:158)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=20 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41f6d6c0 self=0x57600af0
  | sysTid=21260 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1465924288
  | schedstat=( 137061046899 106138943361 2940968 ) utm=10317 stm=3388 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41f6d990> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=20 (AsyncTask #2)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"pool-3-thread-1" prio=5 tid=19 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41ec84e8 self=0x57600688
  | sysTid=21259 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1089548880
  | schedstat=( 333892046105 50531397520 395232 ) utm=24001 stm=9387 core=3
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41cd3cb0> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=19 (pool-3-thread-1)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=18 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41e43190 self=0x57600238
  | sysTid=21258 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1093436480
  | schedstat=( 122133361244 94201913504 2662437 ) utm=9133 stm=3079 core=3
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41e93b30> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=18 (AsyncTask #1)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"pool-1-thread-1" prio=5 tid=17 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41d8d558 self=0x40018928
  | sysTid=21257 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073843576
  | schedstat=( 538748652 44112875 1633 ) utm=30 stm=23 core=2
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41d958b8> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=17 (pool-1-thread-1)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer" daemon prio=5 tid=14 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41d82388 self=0x40ea8430
  | sysTid=21248 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1089147888
  | schedstat=( 135958 26125 2 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41d824a8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
  at com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer.run(Finalizer.java:114)

"OPTMZ" prio=5 tid=12 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41ce5b60 self=0x40f1c8c8
  | sysTid=21243 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1089677856
  | schedstat=( 241167 3985041 22 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41ce5530> (a android.os.ConditionVariable)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at android.os.ConditionVariable.block(ConditionVariable.java:97)
  at crittercism.android.f.run((null):-1)
  at crittercism.android.cq.a((null):-1)
  at crittercism.android.cv.run((null):-1)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Binder_2" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41c97448 self=0x40f17500
  | sysTid=21232 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1089092880
  | schedstat=( 35924382 39652369 228 ) utm=1 stm=2 core=0
  #00  pc 0000cb90  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 00027fcd  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
  #02  pc 00016bfd  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+124)
  #03  pc 000173af  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
  #04  pc 0001b171  /system/lib/libbinder.so
  #05  pc 0001104f  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
  #06  pc 0004ba7b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
  #07  pc 00010bb5  /system/lib/libutils.so
  #08  pc 00012e00  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
  #09  pc 00012558  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_1" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41c971b8 self=0x40eb0008
  | sysTid=21231 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1088983768
  | schedstat=( 41858044 25543380 342 ) utm=2 stm=2 core=0
  #00  pc 0000cb90  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 00027fcd  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+16)
  #02  pc 00016bfd  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+124)
  #03  pc 000173af  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+154)
  #04  pc 0001b171  /system/lib/libbinder.so
  #05  pc 0001104f  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+114)
  #06  pc 0004ba7b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+66)
  #07  pc 00010bb5  /system/lib/libutils.so
  #08  pc 00012e00  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
  #09  pc 00012558  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=8 WAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41c94180 self=0x40e096f0
  | sysTid=21230 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1089149536
  | schedstat=( 193951857 409607638 3031 ) utm=8 stm=10 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41311cf8> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:214)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 WAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41c93fd0 self=0x40ea38c0
  | sysTid=21229 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074231352
  | schedstat=( 2874811820 653275129 6681 ) utm=224 stm=62 core=3
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x413005d0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:169)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 WAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41c93e68 self=0x40ea78a8
  | sysTid=21228 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1089109240
  | schedstat=( 579457779 268872517 10279 ) utm=44 stm=13 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x413004f8> 
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:129)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=5 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41c93d78 self=0x40ed3568
  | sysTid=21227 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1089689680
  | schedstat=( 13840664945 2175691525 62372 ) utm=829 stm=555 core=3
  #00  pc 0000dca0  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
  #01  pc 00012e44  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
  #02  pc 00012ea0  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+60)
  #03  pc 0006f955  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #04  pc 00053b8f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #05  pc 00012e00  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
  #06  pc 00012558  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"JDWP" daemon prio=5 tid=4 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41c93c90 self=0x40dcf718
  | sysTid=21226 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1087520184
  | schedstat=( 164604246 215945407 747 ) utm=14 stm=1 core=1
  #00  pc 0000d758  /system/lib/libc.so (recvmsg+8)
  #01  pc 00060383  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #02  pc 00060581  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #03  pc 0006327b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #04  pc 00053b8f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #05  pc 00012e00  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
  #06  pc 00012558  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41c93b98 self=0x40f01ca8
  | sysTid=21224 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1089261720
  | schedstat=( 89234254 24155125 31 ) utm=4 stm=4 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41c93ab8 self=0x410cfde0
  | sysTid=21222 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1464184336
  | schedstat=( 75670018971 4421244466 25704 ) utm=7432 stm=135 core=3
  #00  pc 0000dca0  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
  #01  pc 00012e44  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
  #02  pc 00012ea0  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+60)
  #03  pc 0006e65b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #04  pc 00053b8f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #05  pc 00012e00  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
  #06  pc 00012558  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

NATIVE THREADS:
"ekeeper.reptile" sysTid=21267 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
  | schedstat=( 18500 0 1 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0

"ekeeper.reptile" sysTid=21268 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
  | schedstat=( 572297498 198605347 10711 ) utm=25 stm=32 core=1

"ekeeper.reptile" sysTid=21269 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
  | schedstat=( 1489497433 692708683 24726 ) utm=39 stm=109 core=2

----- end 21220 -----
```

Some more info in [dumpstate](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22456079/post%20files/SO/20210470/dumpstate_app_anr.txt.gz) file. (Retrieved from device after ANR at /data/log/dumpstate_app_anr.txt.gz) Process ID of app is 16042 with Unix user app_112.  Looking at the more detailed logcat (search for MAIN LOG in the file), it looks like OutOfMemoryException.  But I would expect the JVM to crash and restart, not lockup in this zombie state.  What is keeping the app from crashing successfully?

More info of /proc/PID/ folder in [zip file](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22456079/post%20files/SO/20210470/11.zip) of frozen Android app.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the main thread stack in your ANR trace, where is it?

And, from the "java.lang.ProcessManager" stack, I am guessing you are doing something by forking child processes?

I have met this issue before, it is very strange bug that the the Java process wrapper sometimes got blocked when waiting for the child process to quit.

I am not sure it is a bug, in my case, my child process is already gone, but the main process is still waiting for it in the main thread. Then ANR happened.

Finally, I write some JNI code to wrap C library "system("cmd")" to workaround this issue.

Comment: My app doesn't use any native process control. It doesn't even use `android.os.Process` or `java.lang.Process` (though the thirdparty lib crittercism might.) 

I do believe the main thread being missing is not a very good sign.

Comment: Are you able to log into the device with adb shell, find the PID of your process and cat the file /proc/PID/stack to see the C stack?

Comment: Not rooted device, so `cat /proc/21220/stack` and `kill -3 21220` is not permitted.

Comment: I got this reproduced on an AVD, but the path /proc/PID/stack doesn't exist.  Any other info that might help?  Complete /proc/PID/stack files ziped upp and available here http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22456079/post%20files/SO/20210470/11.zip)